# invert tab index order for two elements without disrupting other elements

Tags: html

i have a page with some standard stuff like header links, links on the left, content then footer links. i want them to be traversible via tabbing.

the problem is my quick search form. rendering from left to right is the box then the button. but in the source code, the button comes first then the box. i want to invert their tab order. is it possible?

currently if you tab through the site:

header links -> left links -> **search button** -> **search box** -> page contents -> footer

it should be like:

header links -> left links -> **search box** -> **search button** -> page contents -> footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather of the problem, the way I would do it would be to create a `<div id(or class)="search">` and put both the box and the button inside. The you can absolutely position the box and button and adjust them within the confines of the `div`  via `top` `bottom` `left` and `right` until they line up correctly. Does that help?

Comment: can you have an example code? i'm not really a fan of absolute positioning tricks.

Comment: Your welcome! I love absolute positioning if you couldn't tell. :)